# Check a value of a key of json in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this function in php

```
<?php function showTable(){
$url = "http://10.0.0.1/lib/api/desk/branch/";

$params = array ("action" => "list","company_key" => "1");

$result=requestURL($url,$params);

$json_a=json_decode(strip_tags($result),true);

?>
```

This is the json I got from the code above. I need to check the key "status". If it has a value "no", it should display an alert that status is not ok. Thanks!

```
{
    "init": [
        {
            "status": "ok",
            "record_count": 9,
            "code": "",
            "message": "",
            "page_count": null,
            "current_page": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using json decode, in PHP?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_php_example.htm

Comment: I updated my answer. Also, remove strip_tags from json_decode.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.

Suppose you hold the JSON in `$json`.

```
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($json, true);

if($jsonDecoded['init'][0]['status'] != 'ok') {
    print "status is not ok :(";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say that json is in $json variable

```
    $json = json_decode($json,true); 
        $status = $json['init'][0]['status'];
        if($status=='ok'){
           # do something here
        }else{
           # display not ok here
        }
```

Comment: You're missing the offset m8.